# Eigen coefficient wise operator with different return type

Tags: c++, eigen

I'd like to have an Eigen coeffientwise operator where the return type differs from the input matrix type, e.g.,

```
struct TimesPi {
  double operator()(int v) { return 3.14 * v; }
};

// in main
Eigen::Vector3i vec_ints(1, 2, 3);
Eigen::Vector3d vec_dbls = vec_ints.unaryExpr<TimesPi>();
```

This results in a compiler error message `error: static assertion failed: YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY`.

How can I produce an elementwise operation that returns a different type?

edit: For the specific case I have (different from example), I cannot use cast (e.g., with a custom Scalar type). I think unaryExpr may be the wrong thing to use here. Perhaps something with CwiseUnaryOp?

A more appropriate example might be

```
struct SomeOperation {
  double operator()(const Foo& v) { return v.attribute; }
};

// in main
Eigen::Matrix<Foo, 3, 1> vec_foos;
Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1> = vec_foos.unaryExpr<SomeOperation>();
```

Comment: I haven't used Eigen, but I can guess from the error message that it's something like `vec_ints.cast<double>().unaryExpr<TimesPi>()`.

Comment: For the specific case I have (different from example), I cannot use cast. I think `unaryExpr` may be the wrong thing to use here. Perhaps something with `CwiseUnaryOp`?

Comment: That looks like an expression template class that shouldn't need to be used explicitly. On the page for it, I also see that it looks like `x * vec` should be allowed directly.

Comment: In this case, the expression template would work fine. The above was just supposed to be a simple example. What would you do with a custom scalar type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is just a simplified example and that in your real-world scenario the functor is much more complex and cannot be accomplished by concatenating standard unary operators. If so, then you have two solutions:

1. Compile in C++11 mode (e.g., `-std=c++11`) so that Eigen can make use of c++11 std::result_of to figure out the return type automatically. (you also need to make your `operator()` const)
2. If you need c++98 compatibility, then you have to tell to Eigen the `result_type` as follows:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

struct TimesPi {
  typedef double result_type;  // needed for c++98/03 only
  double operator()(int v) const { return 3.14 * v; }
};

int main()
{
  Eigen::Vector3i vec_ints(1, 2, 3);
  Eigen::Vector3d vec_dbls = vec_ints.unaryExpr(TimesPi());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. Specifying result_type worked for my custom Scalar type.

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't look like you need to use the struct to create a Unary Expr. Why not just ...

```
Eigen::Vector3i vec_ints(1,2,3);
Eigen::Vector3d vec_dbls = vec_ints.cast<double>() * M_PI;

std::cout << vec_dbls << std::endl;
```

returns ...

```
3.14159
6.28319
9.42478
```